# Azure Backup Change Source Location

Tags: backup, azure, incremental-backup

I have a small client who uses Azure Backup and Replication to perform a cloud backup of profile data and a file share that was sitting on a failing NAS.

I mounted the new NAS via ISCSI to the file server and performed an overnight robocopy of the data from the old NAS to the new. This included the Azure scratch disk. So I disabled the services and used the *Net stop obengine* before performing a regedit to update the new scratch location and then redirected the copy job to the new Drive letter.

Unfortunately this started a new copy job using the new drive directory rather than recognizing the existing data in the cloud. Is there any way to force Azure to continue the incremental copy of the files that are still in the cloud rather than copying the terabit of data across again?

I have tried disconnecting the old NAS and using the same drive letter but it still wants to start a new backup job.